# Variable Number of channels

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I need a convolutional layer which outputs a variable number of channels, depending on the input.
`conv2d(filters = variable_number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model cannot have varying number of filters depending on the input. The model need to have below arguments to be fixed for it to be trained.

- Name and type of all layers in the model.
- Output shape for each layer.
- Number of weight parameters of each layer.
- The inputs each layer receives.
- The total number of trainable and non-trainable parameters of the model.

If you have varying number of channels, then the model architecture is changing for different input and thus all the above listed points get impacted.

You can build a model with all the fixed parameters and later use `dropout` for the layer based on the input. But again the dropout is a regularization technique, Simply put, dropout refers to ignoring units (i.e. neurons) during the training phase of certain set of neurons which is chosen at random. By “ignoring”, I mean these units are not considered during a particular forward or backward pass.

OR

**The most appropriate solution would be -**

1. Build multiple input layer for different inputs.
2. Concatenate all these layers, but make sure the output shape of all these layers are same in case of Convolution layers else concatenate throws error.
3. Add the remaining layers of the model.

Below is an example for this -

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, concatenate, Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

input_img1 = Input(shape=(44,44,3))
x1 = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img1)

input_img2 = Input(shape=(34,34,3))
x2 = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img2)
# Zero Padding of 5 at the top, bottom, left and right side of an image tensor
x3 = ZeroPadding2D(padding = (5,5))(x2)

# Concatenate works as layers have same size output
x4 = concatenate([x1,x3])

output = Dense(18, activation='relu')(x4)

model = Model(inputs=[input_img1,input_img2], outputs=output)

model.summary()
```

Output -

```
Model: "model_22"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_91 (InputLayer)           (None, 34, 34, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_90 (InputLayer)           (None, 44, 44, 3)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_73 (Conv2D)              (None, 34, 34, 3)    84          input_91[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_72 (Conv2D)              (None, 44, 44, 3)    84          input_90[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding2d_14 (ZeroPadding2 (None, 44, 44, 3)    0           conv2d_73[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_30 (Concatenate)    (None, 44, 44, 6)    0           conv2d_72[0][0]                  
                                                                 zero_padding2d_14[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_47 (Dense)                (None, 44, 44, 18)   126         concatenate_30[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 294
Trainable params: 294
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Hope this answers you question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @m.a. k. - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.